# Magento 2 observer, dispatch catalog_product_save_after event when update products programmatically

Tags: magento2, observer-pattern, m2e-pro

I have to dispatch event catalog_product_save_before or catalog_product_save_after event, while update a lot of products programmatically.
I run a script that call updateAttributes() method that dispatch event catalog_product_attribute_update_before, but m2epro module does not update amazon's price if I don't call catalog_product_save_after ord catalog_product_save_before

what do you think is the best solution for this need?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are also trying to update price for the product along with amazon price when using your script. If you have any functionality/dependencies to customize the price before updating regular price, then **catalog_product_save_after** is better approach to fetch the calculated price and update amazon price attribute. If you don't have such dependencies, you can use either of them and there won't be any difference at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have to update 75000 products in 2 hours maximum.
Do you think I can make the process faster by directly modifying the class that manages the method updateAttributes()